# How to enable warning "control reaches end of non-void function" for main(), gcc 4.3

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings

I'm using `gcc -O -Wall -Wextra` to try to help students find faults in their code.  Imagine my surprise when this code, which never returns a value from `main()`, passes without a warning:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if(argc > 2)
    fprintf(stderr, "Too many arguments\n");
  else if(argc == 2){
    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(file != NULL)
      doSomethingNifty(file);
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "File unable to be opened\n");
  }
  else{
    soSomethingNifty(stdin);
  }
}
```

After trying everything else I can think of, I finally tried changing the *name* of the function.  If I call it `maim`, I get what I expect:

```
mumble.c: In function 'maim':
mumble.c:45: error: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Evidently our good friends <s>at the Free Software Foundation</s> on the C99 Standards Committee think that my students don't want to be warned of potential bugs in `main()`, but only in other functions.  So my question: **how do I enable this warning for `main()`?**

I have RTFM but was not enlightened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return 0 is implicitly added for main in C99 and C++. The default standard (gnu90) probably also does this.

Yes, if you build with gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c89 without a return in main, you do get the warning.

Comment: How awful!  Thanks for the info.